# Is there a Javascript LLVM IR bitcode interpreter?

Tags: javascript, llvm, interpreter, llvm-ir

I'm trying to run an existing C project in a browser without relying on addons/plugins/etc. Sources are 3MB, resulting compiled bitcode (llvm-link) is 3.5M.

When running the bitcode with lli the memory use is about 150MB, same as when compiling a native ELF binary and running it.

Emscripten (-O2 --closure 0) compiles the bitcode to a 24MB .js file, and when running that with Node.js, I run out of memory (top shows about 2GB of memory use).

As the jslinux demo has shown, it should be possible to interpret native code. It should arguably be easier to interpret compiled bitcode with acceptable performance. My question is whether there is any project that tries to interpret LLVM IR in javascript (as opposed to translating the IR to javascript, like Emscripten, mandreel and others do).

Comment: If you want to run native code in the browser, did you consider Google's Native Client?

Comment: Compile lli to JS and run it on bitcode.

Comment: Eli Bendersky: NaCl is the only approach that looks realistic right now, but it would leave IE and Firefox out.

Comment: arrowdodger: for sure. the smallest build of lli I could come up with is 5.5MB (with LLVM libs linked in).

Comment: For future readers: Google Native Client (NaCl) is gone. It never caught on. Consider a native JS approach.

Comment: For future readers: you can try WebAssembly, which is now supported by all major browsers. There is an LLVM backend for WebAssembly, so it should be pretty easy to compile some C code (or LLVM IR) into wasm.